# ./jmap command works when script is run manually but fails when run as cronjob

Tags: cron, bash-scripting, rhel-6

I have a fairly simple script written for calculating heap size and it uses `./jmap`. 
The script first finds the process id and saves it in a variable `PID`. The same `PID` is given as a variable in the script as follows:

```
$JAVA_BIN./jmap -heap $(cat $PID) > test.txt
```

When script is run manually, it works fine. And instead of variable if I directly give `PID` as number in the above command, even the `cronjob` runs successfully.

But if I give it like above, the `cronjob` outputs the man value of `jmap` as output for test.txt:

```
Usage:
    jmap [option] <pid>
        (to connect to running process)
    jmap [option] <executable <core>
        (to connect to a core file)
    jmap [option] [server_id@]<remote server IP or hostname>
        (to connect to remote debug server)
```

It's like it's not able to read the `PID` value from the variable, I am running `crontab -e`

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The command sequence `$(cat $PID)` is not valid. 
With the given sequence `cat` will interpret the content of the variable `$PID` as a path to a file. As most likely there will not be such a file, this command will fail (or print the content of that file).

I guess what you were looking for `$(echo $PID)`, which will print the content of the variable $PID to stdout.

I'm not into Java but I think `$JAVA_BIN./jmap -heap $PID > test.txt` should do what you want.

Comment: Using echo worked. Also after I added " " -> "$(cat $PID)", even it worked. But yeah, using echo for this makes much more sense. Thanks.